# R shiny selectInput reactivity issues

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I recently asked a question about issues with reactivity in Shiny, and I modified my code due to the comments I received, but I still cannot get it to work. As I mentioned before, I know that without the reactivity, the plot works, so it's definitely a reactivity issue.

In my UI I have a selectInput with choices A, B, C, D.  (Corresponding to 4 data frames A, B, C, D).

In my server:

```
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "purple")

data <- reactive({
    if(input$selectInput == "A"){
        A
    } else if(input$selectInput == "B") {
        B
    } else if(input$selectInput == "C") {
        C
    } else if(input$selectInput == "D") {
        D
    }

   data <- na.omit(as.data.frame(data$cover_group))
   names(data) <- c("tmp")
 })


   group_factor <- reactive({
      group_factor <- as.factor(data()$tmp)
     group_factor <- fct_recode(group_factor, OTHER = "E", OTHER = "SPONGES", OTHER = "F", OTHER = "G", OTHER = "H", OTHER = "I", OTHER = "J")
            })



 bar <- reactive({
     ggplot(data = data()) +
            geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = group_factor(), y = ..count../sum(..count..)), fill = colors) + xlab("Cover Group") + ylab("Percent")
         })


 observe({
   output$coverTypeBarChart <- renderPlot(bar())
        })
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: The error is: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character

Comment: anything reactive returns values as type character. try using `as.type(reactive())` where type is your needed type and reactive is your reactive function name.

Comment: OK, I did  ggplot(data = as.data.frame(data()) and got the error: "The $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".

Comment: try using different names. `data` and `data()` is going to cause you issues

Comment: You need to create some sample data, generate a minimal working example so others can better help you. Just posting server code and hope others can find the problem by gazing on them seldom work unless it's too obvious.

Comment: And basic debugging skills should help: place a `browser()` call after data is generated, run the app, inspect data to see what has go wrong.

Comment: Without looking too closely, you have to return a value from your reactives! Use return(data) and return(group_factor) etc. explicitely (or just put the make "group_factor" the last line of the reactive without anything else, same effect)

Comment: And you need to learn reactive basics. Putting ggplot in a reactive expression, then put reactive expression in renderPlot call, using observe, all of these are not right in your case. Why so many shiny beginners are using `observe`, and I don't recall any reactive tutorial I read using it. Are you using some old tutorial or some old example code?

Comment: It was my understanding reactive is used to store values, and observe is used to perform some action. I forget where I read this, and I may well be completely wrong.

Comment: an observer is used for its resulting side effects. a reactive is used to return a value. a reactiveValue is used to store a value